# Coldfusion Webservice and SOAP

Tags: soap, coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-9, webservice-client

I am using coldfusion and IIS 7.5
Problem is that when the web service has 500 error, it returns HTML instead of XML.

Can anyone help me in fixing this please.

Thanks.

Comment: If you really want help, you're going to need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Internal Server Error, may have occurred because of a data type mismatch. The server is expecting one data type but you are sending a different data type for the input parameter. Please check the input format of the web service that you are calling.

For example: If you try to consume a web service method which takes a SOAP object as an input parameter and you call that method with a different parameter other than SOAP the server will throw a 500 error.